# Default hide an image (or anything) in a question/answer

Tags: feature-request, images

As we can hide by default snippets, can we do the same for other elements?

```html
Default hidden snippet
```

---

Initially my question was about hiding by default images. For example this *(cute)* cat picture is really big, and I would like it to be hidable by default.

[image]

In a more general way, I think we could create a feature to **hide everything in a block has long it was not being clicked** (like the `[spoiler]` tag in forums).

```
[spoiler] Whatever you want to hide. [/spoiler]
```

What do you think about it? What could be the synthax?

Comment: Use a snippet and try to break out of its sandbox to manipulate the DOM of the post to insert an image…?

Comment: Seriously though, you could use a thumbnail and link that to the full-sized image as a workaround.

Comment: @deceze I was wondering if there was something similar to `[spoiler]` on forums, (*a tag in which you can put everything you want that will be hidded as long it has not been clicked*). So I guess the answer is no!

Comment: Best I can do is [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290572/291223)

Comment: Yeah, I agree, `[thumbnail]` or so could be useful.

Comment: @deceze Should I change tags to `feature-request` instead of `support`?

Comment: Seems reasonable, yes.

Comment: I think allowing this would be asking for a purrfect catastrophe.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a big fan of "hidden" information—it is hard to see. Furthermore, I think it's disorienting when clicking or hovering makes a *giant* image or block of text appear.

The correct way to do this would be to use a thumbnail, and make that thumbnail link to the full-size image, so it is available if someone wants it.

This is simple to accomplish. When you insert an image, the following Markdown is automatically generated:

```
[![enter descriptive text][1]][1]
```

That's the *full-sized* image, linking to the full-sized image. Sometimes that's appropriate, but in this case, we want a thumbnail. So, change the Markdown to:

```
[![enter descriptive text][2]][1]
```

`[1]` should be the URL of your full-size image, the automatically generated slug at ImgUr. `[2]` is that same URL, but with an `m` (or `s`) appended to the end of that slug. `m` has ImgUr automatically render a medium-sized thumbnail, while `s` requests a small-sized thumbnail.

The net effect is simply:

[image: a cat photo (medium thumbnail)]

or

[image: a cat photo (small thumbnail)]

If absolutely necessary, you could combine this thumbnail with the "spoiler" Markdown, but please use this sparingly. It doesn't really make sense to have "spoilers" on a programming Q&A site.

> [image: a cat photo (small thumbnail)]

Unfortunately, as you can see, "spoiler" always uses a blockquote-style formatting, and the underline on image links does not disappear. It doesn't look great. This serves as another reminder not to use it without a very good reason.